# remove/delete a value from a field with multiple values separated with semicolons

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the following command in Android to add a a value when needed in a a field that has multiple values separated with semicolons.

Table name is `system` and contain 3 fields: `ID`, `Name`, and `Value`.

The `value` field contains several values seprated with semicolons:

`Wifi;Mobile Data;BlueTooth` etc.

Now if I want to add a value in it the following command work perfectly, in this case I add `Data;` where the `Name` field is `notification_panel_active_app_list`:

```
UPDATE system
SET value = (SELECT value || 'Data;'
             FROM system
             WHERE name = 'notification_panel_active_app_list')
WHERE name = 'notification_panel_active_app_list';
```

Now I want to remove a value from this multiple-value field, how to do it? Let's say I want to remove 'Bluetooth;', how should I do it?  I tried putting DELETE instead of SELECT but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why are you using this unwieldy format, and not a properly normalized table? Can you change the DB structure?

Comment: It is how it is in Android, I am not programmer all i need is to able to remove an entry, adding it is working with aboive mentioned instructions in an .sql file that is then luanched by a script in Custom Recovery  with also following command and it work perfectly.  All i need is just an other command to do the opposite to delete an entery   #!/sbin/sh
/sbin/mount -a
/tmp/sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db < /tmp/toggles.sql

Comment: You should use **2 tables**. One "Master" and one "Details". The Master table will contain an index to address all the records with the same id in the Details Table. The SELECT will include a JOIN, to read from both tables. Read something about database **normalization**, as suggested by @CL. It is the **R** in RDBMS (**Relational** DataBase Management System).

Comment: Guys you are not understanding it. This is database and table is part of Android OS System , I am not creating any table or database and I dont need to.  I just need to add or remove a value in that particular field to unable option in status bar of the mobile phone. These are built in the system, I am not going to mess with the whole system with thousand of entries.   I just need to know ho to remove a value,  If I can add it without issue with above command in mu original  there must be a way to remove a value too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command to add a value can be simplified because the old value in the `value` column is available directly:

```
UPDATE system
SET value = value || 'Data;'
WHERE name = 'notification_panel_active_app_list';
```

---

To remove a value, you can use the [replace function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace):

```
UPDATE system
SET value = replace(value, 'BlueTooth;', '')
WHERE name = 'notification_panel_active_app_list';
```

However, this works correctly only if this value is actually followed by a semicolon, and if there is no other entry that has this value as a suffix (such as `RedAndBlueTooth;`).

Comment: Thank you so much CL, it work great :)   As you said it wont work for RedAndBluetooth, fornow i dont need to remove such value, but if I do will there be any workarround ?